# Angularjs ng-class condition for window.location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to unset/set a css class at a specific path url

I tried writing this code, but without any success

```
<div ng-class="window.location.toString().includes('ocs')? '' :'icon-home'"></div>
```

in chrome console i see this:

```
<div ng-class="window.location.toString().includes('ocs')? '' :'icon-home'" class="icon-home"></div>
```

I need to create a new angularjs module and scope for do this?

Comment: can you be more precise on "without any success"? Do you have any error? Anything unexpected?

Comment: I see the class in html, so the condition doesn't work

<div ng-class="window.location.toString().includes('ocs')? '' :'icon-home'" class="icon-home"></div>

Comment: if you try to debug with a `console.log`, what do you get for `window.location.toString()`?

Comment: {{console.log(window.location.toString())}} doesn't work inside html  code, no message no erros, with console i have the entire path and the condition works

Comment: `{{}}` is for variable interpolation, `console.log` is not a variable from your scope, to debug the code, you should either place the line in the controller, or remove the `{{}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are clearing the class if location contains 'ocs', the correct approach should be this:

```
// in you angularjs controller: 
$scope.containesOCS = window.location.toString().includes('ocs');
```

And in the html:

```
<div ng-class="{'icon-home': !containesOCS}"></div>
```

And if you haven't created an angular module or controller, please do so first. Without the 
ng-app the angular attributes won't work.

Comment: <div ng-class="{'icon-home': !containesOCS}" class="icon-home"></div> the result

Comment: I have two crontroller in my page, maincontroller and summarycontroller, i added in both of them the scope

Comment: Please specify what is the problem with the result. It is working as I expect and so as your location doesn't contain the subtring "ocs" it is applying the class 'icon-home' to your div. If it did, there will be no classes applied. And if you want to apply the class IF it contains "ocs", just remove the '!' from in front of the containsOCS variable in the condition.

Comment: https://localhost:8443/digital-signature/ocs/wizard/1549460936017#/ my windows location string

Comment: Does this work `<div ng-class="{'icon-home': containesOCS}"></div>` ?

Comment: No, i see this in console:

<div ng-class="{'icon-home': !containesOCS}" class="icon-home"></div>, i added scope in two controller that are loaded in my app, i know because i see console logs

Comment: You should really understand how conditional operators work, and also notice the result you posted now still has the `!` I removed in my comment above. You just gave me the same output from before without making the change from `!containesOCS` to `containesOCS`. You are just saying this doesn't work that doesn't work, but please reply to what is it you want. I already asked you above.

Comment: Please provide an upvote and mark the answer as correct if you find the answer that solved your problem. Good to hear the solution worked.